# How to produce graphics based on rs.surv (relative survival in R)

Tags: r, graphics

I am trying to produce nice graphics based on relative survival in R.

I have loaded

```
library(relsurv)
library(survminer)

fit.hist <- rs.surv(Surv(time,cens)~ordered(Hist)+
ratetable(age = age, sex = sex, year = year), 
ratetable = poptab, method="pohar-perme")
```

But when i run this

```
plot.hist<- ggsurvplot(fit.hist, conf.int=F, surv.scale=c("percent"),
risk.table=T, ggtheme = theme_bw(), risk.table.fontsize=3.5, 
xlim=c(0,19.5), ylim=c(0,1), break.time.by=1)
```

R returns an Error Message: *The `data` argument should be provided either to ggsurvfit or survfit.*

Do you have any experience in producing nice graphic in R based upon Relative Survival?

Regards,
C.